# Key release event not recognized GTK

Tags: c, user-interface, keyboard, gtk, gtk3

I am writing a C program to control an ARDrone, and would like the drone to move as long as a key is pressed down, and when the key is no longer pressed down I want it to stop moving.  I attached both a key_press_event and key_release_event to the window I created, and here is the callback function:

```
gint key_press_cb(GtkWidget *widget, 
                GdkEventKey *kevent, 
                gpointer data)
{ 
unsigned int key;
int res;

/* While a key is pressed the drone moves,
 * when the key is released it is put back into hover mode */
if(kevent->type == GDK_KEY_RELEASE) {
    // Hover mode
    printf("--- Hover Mode ---\n");
    ardrone_at_set_progress_cmd(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    //res = keyboard_update(BACKSPACE);
} else if(kevent->type == GDK_KEY_PRESS) {

    key = kevent->keyval;
    g_message("Key pressed: %c [%d]", key, key);

    res = keyboard_update(key); 
}

return TRUE;
}
```

I will get a key release event if I hold down the key for a short period of time, but when holding it down for 2+ seconds I will not see the key release event.  I was thinking it could be because I am constantly receiving key_press_events while holding down a key; is there any way to disable that repeat?

Comment: The code you have posted is working fine for me. Perhaps there is some other widget in the window that has focus and is swallowing the key release events.

Comment: I'll post my entire code, I tried setting the focus to the window but it seems like it is going to the 'w' button by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem if anyone was wondering.  In my `keyboard_update()` function I was calling `g_signal_emit_by_name(G_OBJECT(/*button*/), "activate", NULL)` to have the button pressed down when the user pressed the corresponding key.  Once I removed this feature the key release event was being recognized again.  Not sure why this happens but I can live without this feature for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following

```
void gtk_widget_add_events(GtkWidget* widget, gint event_mask);
```

where `event_mask` should be `GDK_KEY_RELEASE_MASK | GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK`
And you should also trigger the event handler on the `key-release-event`

For a more detailed answer more code and output information is required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that and am still having the same issues.  I'll edit the main post to include the relevant code for creating the window and adding the signals/events.  I can attach my entire code here if you would like but it is kind of long.